# How to get String representation of ObjectId from response body?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, objectid

I am trying to create a simple API which works with MongoDB documents created from this class:

```
@Document()
data class Student(@Id val id: ObjectId?,
               val firstName: String,
               val secondName: String) {}
```

And I have a REST controller which returns me Student documents.

```
{
    "id": {
        "timestamp": 1657005140,
        "date": "2022-07-05T07:12:20.000+00:00"
    },
    "firstName": "Test",
    "secondName": "Test"
}
```

But I also need a controller which returns me documents by id. How can I put this JSON id with timestamp and date in a request param like `/getByName?id=` ? Maybe there is a way to get an ID in one-string representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my ObjectId was serialised.

To get simple one-string value I needed just to add:     `@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer::class)`

So my document looks like this:

```
@Document()
data class Student(
               @Id
               @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer::class)
               val id: ObjectId?,
               val firstName: String,
               val secondName: String) {}
```